# npm: missing start script even though start is defined in the package.json file

Tags: node.js, npm

I have start defined in my scripts on `pakcage.json` but npm still gives me the start not found error

```
"scripts": {
    "start": "node server.js",
    "server":"nodemon server",
    "client":"npm start --prefix client",
    "dev":"concurrently \"npm run server\" \"npm run client\""
 },
```

Comment: Sounds like the directory you're running `npm start` from isn't the one with `package.json`

Comment: `pakcage.json` typo mistake with the filename.

Answer (score 0):

This is for Node version `10.16.0` on Windows 10 
Basically, you don't need a start script. In your package.json file, 
`...
    "main": "server.js",
...`

and in the terminal go to your project directory and type 
`nodemon`

This will start your app upon your configurations!

That should help!